# Image processing using the frequency domain - duplicate image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transform, fft

I have an image that consist of 2 identical images, one is translated.

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me4iX.jpg)

now, i want to fix it. I used the translation property of transform fourier:

$f(x-x_0,y-y_0)\leftrightarrowF(u,v)e^{-2{\pi}i(ux_0/{N}+ vy_0/M)}$

I measured the distance between the 2 images: the x distance is 24 pixels and the y distance is 4 pixels. In the code: x_d and y_d.

then I just divided all pixels in the  frequency domain image by the exponent expression from the formula + 1 (the 1 come from the image that was not translated).

I can't figure out what the problem...

this is my code:

```
function [  ] = f(  )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

FileName='dog.tif';

%--- Read Image ---
im = readImage(FileName);
imshow(im);

%--- apply FFT on the given image ---
fftIm = fftshift(fft2(im));

%--- apply LOG and abs for plotting the transform --- 
fLog = log(1 + abs(fftIm));

%----modify the image in the frequency domain-------
fftImMod=fftIm;
x_d=24;           %x distance between the 2 images
y_d=4;            %y distance between the 2 images
N = 305;        %the dimensions of the image NxM = 305x305 
M = 305;        %the dimensions of the image NxM = 305x305 

for r=1:size(fftIm,1)

      for k=1:size(fftIm,2)

          divisionVal =  1+exp((-2*(pi)*1i)*(r*x_d/N + k*y_d/M));

          fftImMod(r,k)=fftIm(r,k)/divisionVal;

      end;
  end;

%--- apply LOG and abs for plotting the modified transform --- 
fLogAfterMod = log(1 + abs(fftImMod));

%--- return to the image space ---
result=ifft2(fftshift(fftImMod));

% --- display results ---
colormap(gray)
subplot(2,2,1),imagesc(im); title('Original Image')
subplot(2,2,2),imagesc(fLog); title('Fourier Image')
subplot(2,2,3),imagesc(fLogAfterMod); title('Modified Fourier')
subplot(2,2,4),imagesc(real(result)); title('Result Image')

end
```

and here is the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCpm2.jpg)

Any help will be appreciated. 
thanks.

Comment: What you want to do is registration. Take a look to the TurboReg plugin in ImageJ, it does that really well. I know some basic algorithm are also already implemented in MatLab.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately I can not use plugins.

Comment: All the source code (basic java) is also available, just in case you want to translate it. I have big needs about registration, and TurboReg was the best algorithm I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- swapped x and y in the definition of the division array
- removed fftshift
- added -1 in the argumend of the exponent for the counters
- added a BW limitation for result plotting

  ```
  %UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
  %   Detailed explanation goes here
  FileName='/tmp/me4iX.jpg';
  %--- Read Image ---
  im = imread(FileName);
  im=im(:,:,1)

  %--- apply FFT on the given image ---
  fftIm = (fft2(im));

  %--- apply LOG and abs for plotting the transform --- 
  fLog = log(1 + abs(fftIm));

  %----modify the image in the frequency domain-------
  fftImMod=fftIm;
  x_d=24;           %x distance between the 2 images
  y_d=4;            %y distance between the 2 images
  N = 305;        %the dimensions of the image NxM = 305x305 
  M = 305;        %the dimensions of the image NxM = 305x305 

  for r=1:size(fftIm,1)
        for k=1:size(fftIm,2)
            divisionVal(r,k) =  1+exp((-2*(pi)*1i)*((r-1)*y_d/N + (k-1)*x_d/M));    
        end;
    end;


    fftImMod=fftIm./divisionVal;

  %--- apply LOG and abs for plotting the modified transform --- 
  fLogAfterMod = log(1 + abs(fftImMod));

  %--- return to the image space ---
  N=60;
  result=ifft2((fftImMod([1:N end-N-2:end],[1:N end-N-2:end])));

  % --- display results ---
  colormap(gray)
  subplot(2,2,1),imagesc(im); title('Original Image')
  subplot(2,2,2),imagesc(fLog); title('Fourier Image')
  subplot(2,2,3),imagesc(fLogAfterMod); title('Modified Fourier')
  subplot(2,2,4),imagesc(abs(result)); title('Result Image')
  %set(gca,'clim',[0 250])
  ```